# Overlapping background images of separate <div>s creates darker shadow than by themselves

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a problem with overlapping background images which causes a darker shadow when they overlap than when they do not which creates an uneven shadow.

I have a box which is flexible in height with somewhat transparent background images with shadows to create nice borders. The box is essentially 3  elements.

You can find an image of the bottom left corner of the box here: http://img251.imageshack.us/i/overlappingbgs.png/

And the individual backgrounds here:
http://img822.imageshack.us/g/bgtopm.png/

And the code for the box:

```
<div class="centerbox"> <!-- Background image fixed at the bottom. -->
   <div class="head">   <!-- Background image fixed at the top. -->
      ...
   </div>
   <div class="body">   <!-- Vertically repeated background image. -->
      ...
   </div> 
</div>
```

As you can see, there is a darker shadow when the bottom and the repeated middle image overlap (the red area), because of the fact that the background image at the bottom is too tall.

I can not make the image smaller because sometimes that will create a gap in the shadow when there is a margin-bottom set for the last element in the  element.

Anyone with any advice or suggestions of how I can fix this?

Comment: You just have to make sure that the separate divs do not overlap. I can't really tell you how exactly to do this while keeping the rest of the page the same without seeing your page.

Answer (score 0):

Those png files are semi-transparent (they have alpha channel), so when they overlap they blend together, in your case you're effectively getting a double shadow.

If you have a solid background colour for the rest of your site (e.g. plain white) then you could just convert those images to be non-transparent; you'll still get the shadow effect, but only on a white background.

Comment: Thanks for you answer and that would probably work on a site with a fixed background color. The problem is that this site has a background gradient on the <body> element which means they have to be transparent because they can be placed on a different background color.

Answer (score 0):

For this case can't you just add a solid background color to class="body"?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but no, since the box must be able to be positioned over any background color (not just white).

Comment: And it's not possible to change the markup to:

    <div class="centerbox"> <!-- No background. -->
        <div class="head">   <!-- Background image fixed at the top. -->
        ...
        </div>
        <div class="body">   <!-- Vertically repeated background image. -->
        ...
        </div>
        <div class="foot">   <!-- Background image fixed at the bottom. -->
        ...
        </div>
</div>

?